# Warning: get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, integer given

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, orm

I don't know what's the problem when i want to insert some data to the database it show this error

```
<?php

namespace ArticleBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * ArticleRate
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="article_rate")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="ArticleBundle\Repository\ArticleRateRepository")
 */
class ArticleRate
{

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="date")
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Article")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="article_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */

    private $idArticle;

    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="GUBundle\Entity\Utilisateur")
     *
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $idUser;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->date = new \DateTime();

    }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set date
     *
     * @param \DateTime $date
     *
     * @return ArticleRate
     */
    public function setDate($date)
    {
        $this->date = $date;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get date
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDate()
    {
        return $this->date;
    }

    /**
     * Set idArticle
     *
     * @param integer $idArticle
     *
     * @return ArticleRate
     */
    public function setIdArticle($idArticle)
    {
        $this->idArticle = $idArticle;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get idArticle
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getIdArticle()
    {
        return $this->idArticle;
    }

    /**
     * Set idUser
     *
     * @param string $idUser
     *
     * @return ArticleRate
     */
    public function setIdUser($idUser)
    {
        $this->idUser = $idUser;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get idUser
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getIdUser()
    {
        return $this->idUser;
    }
}

    /**
     * @param $id
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
    public function AimeArticlesAction($id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $article=new ArticleRate();
        $article->setIdArticle(1);
        $article->setIdUser(1);
        dump($article);
        $article=(object) $article;
        $em->persist($article);
        $em->flush();
        return new JsonResponse("yes");
    }

}
```

Comment: maybe show us the method used and what you're passing into it... maybe it's an integer!

Comment: this is my methode I tried to force it to be an opject
    public function AimeArticlesAction($id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $article=new ArticleRate();
        $article->setIdArticle(1);
        $article->setIdUser(1);
        dump($article);
        $article=(object) $article;
        $em->persist($article);
        $em->flush();
        return new JsonResponse("yes");
    }

}

Comment: it in the end of my code please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems clear to me: you give an integer (1) and doctrine expects an object.

Doctrine is managing object. These mean you should use `$article->getUser()->getId()` instead of `$article->getUserId()`.

For your specific probleme: those 2 functions expect objects

```
    $article->setIdArticle(1);
    $article->setIdUser(1);
```

That's why you should name those method `Article` And `User`.
You can give them an proxy object by using `getReference`

```
$article->setUser($this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getReference(User:class, 1));
```

Please read the doctrine documentation it seems to me you are far from the good practices

Comment: Thank you so much , I didn't know about that I still learning about that tricky doctrine yes I have long road to master it, thank you for the help.

Comment: No problem! Read carefully symfony examples and doctrine documentation you will learn a lot